# How to display an image from a url in android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am working on my first android application. I need to display an image from a url in my app. I tried in the following way:

Mainactivity file:

```
public class MainViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_view);

     int loader = R.drawable.loader;

        // Imageview to show
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        // Image url
        String image_url = "http://..../landing.png";

        // ImageLoader class instance
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());


        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_view, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here i am getting an error in the line int loader = R.drawable.loader;

The class file are:

FileCache.java

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context){
    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url){
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear(){
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    if(files==null)
        return;
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}
```

}

ImageLoader.java

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
{
    stub_id = loader;
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(loader);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u;
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

}
```

MemoryCache.java

```
public class MemoryCache {
private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new     HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());

public Bitmap get(String id){
    if(!cache.containsKey(id))
        return null;
    SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
    return ref.get();
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
    cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
}

public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}
}
```

Utils.java

```
public class Utils {
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
}
```

Please help to fix that error and see if there is any problem in my code. I have set the required permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: You'd save yourself a lot of time if you used https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader or http://square.github.io/picasso/.

Comment: will you able to put that Logcat values

Comment: If you want to download the multiple images or single image

Comment: @NaveenKumar single image in this case

Comment: Has **loader** named image in your drawable folder?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Thats the issue when i give the name in drawable folder as loader and save it nothing happens and the name is again removed automatically

Comment: save it with another name.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA should i change the complete name i.e should i change loader name in all appearnces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I hope this answer will help you alot I designed this project to download Image from url and store in cache memory and you can use the particular image to your project All the best **If you have any doubt** in that project you will Comment me i will explain the each and every step in that project...
  All the best...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView button;
private BitmapFactory.Options mBitmapOptions;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private TextView mTime;
private ProgressBar bar;
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
private SeekBar seekbar;
private Button change;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    mTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change);
    mBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    mBitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            mBitmapOptions);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapOptions.outWidth,
            mBitmapOptions.outHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    mBitmapOptions.inBitmap = mBitmap;
    mBitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            mBitmapOptions);
    button.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);     
    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
            // number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }
    };
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(mMemoryCache.size());
    System.out.println(mMemoryCache.evictionCount());
    bar.setMax(Images.imageThumbUrls.length - 1);
    seekbar.setMax(Images.imageThumbUrls.length - 1);
    bar.setProgress(0);
    seekbar.setProgress(0);
    for (String string : Images.imageUrls) {
        String position = String.valueOf(i);
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(position);
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, string);          
        i++;
    }
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if (Images.imageUrls.length > progress) {
                if (getBitmapFromMemCache(String.valueOf(progress)) != null) {
                    button.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromMemCache(String
                            .valueOf(progress)));
                } else {
                    // BitmapWorkerTask task = new
                    // BitmapWorkerTask(String.valueOf(progress));
                    // task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,Images.imageUrls[progress]);
                }
            }

        }
    });
    change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMemoryCache.evictAll();
            System.out.println(mMemoryCache.size());
            System.out.println(mMemoryCache.evictionCount());
            bar.setMax(Images.imageUrls.length - 1);
            seekbar.setMax(Images.imageThumbUrls.length - 1);
            bar.setProgress(0);
            seekbar.setProgress(0);
            int i = 0;                              
            for (String string : Images.imageUrls) {
                String position = String.valueOf(i);
                BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(position);
                task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, string);                  
                i++;
            }

        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String position, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(position) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(position, bitmap);
    }
}

public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    final String imageKey = String.valueOf(resId);

    final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        button.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String imageKey) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(imageKey);
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String position = null;

    // Decode image in background.
    public BitmapWorkerTask(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(200);
            connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
            int v = connection.getContentLength() > 0 ? connection
                    .getContentLength() : 0;
            if (v > 0) {                    
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                        connection.getInputStream(), 32 * 1024);
                return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(in, 1000, 1000);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            addBitmapToMemoryCache(position, result);
            // button.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromMemCache(position));
            mTime.setText(position);
            bar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(position));
      //                System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(InputStream in, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) throws IOException {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    in.mark(in.available());
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
    in.reset();
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

UrlImageViewHelper is an open source library([see here](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)) you can use this to display image from url. There is a method `UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(ImagView imageview, String url )` use this method to show image from url.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Picasso
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Picasso handles all the hassles required to display images from URL.